# How to check if a value of the input is number or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem here, I want to check if the value of the input is going to be a number or not on keyup. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $('input').keyup(function () {
 var check_nm = $('input').val();
 if(check_nm != "123"){
   console.log('not number');
 }else{
   console.log('is number');
 }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7537247/dep10oL6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
  var check_nm = $('input').val();
  if (isNaN(check_nm) || check_nm.trim() == "") {
    console.log('not number');
  }else{
    console.log('is number');
   }
});
```

Use a combination of isNaN and.trim() == "" to ensure that blank spaces are not counted as numbers

You can also use isNaN(parseFloat(check_nm)) or $.isNumeric(a), which basically runs isNaN(parseFloat())

Comment: This is a correct answer. isNaN should work.

Comment: @jesusbet Blank spaces fail the isNaN test, so you have to do the "" condition. Try isNaN(" ") in your browser to verify

Comment: Nice and easy, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @PhilipA yeah, that's whay I say your answer is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the number is NOT a number by calling `isNaN(num)` so if you want the opposite it will be `!isNaN()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use unary operator `+` to convert the value to a number. And then check if it's `NaN`:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function () {
    var check_nm = +this.value;
    console.log(isNaN(check_nm) ? 'not number' : 'is number');
});
```

Note whitespaces and empty string will be converted to `0`, so they will be considered a number. If you don't want that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/1529630.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `$.isNumeric()`.

[Docs @ jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/) and [cool discussion @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/532551)